# Is 26 pound dog protected with Heartgard blue?

Tags: dogs, medicines

My dog weighs 26 pounds and I have several Heartgard chews for up to 25 pounds. Is he protected with one blue or do I need to order and give Heartgard for 26 to 50lbs?

Comment: Also, what did the vet say when you asked him?

Comment: The manufacturer is telling you they think the dose will be slightly lower than they would recommend.  Whether that's still enough to be effective will vary in a case by case basis. No promises.